# How can I get a Garamond font?

Tags: fonts, garamond

I am trying to use Garamond font. How do I go about getting this font?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\singlespacing
\usepackage{varwidth}
\geometry{margin=1.5in}
\title{}
\date{}
\author{}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Do you want Garamond as default? Or do you want it just for the title for some reason? Probably your MWE should produce some characters in the output. Or do you want to use Garamond only for the page numbers? Single spacing is default - you don't need `setspace` for this.

Comment: Wow!  Quick response!  Awesome!  Ummm...I want to use it as default...like...for everything...I am so bad at this LaTex thing...I am trying to get better, though!

Comment: No: I don't have it installed.  I didn't know I had to install anything.

Comment: You may not need to. Are you using TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, ConTeXt or something else to compile? If you are using an editor, this is probably set in the preferences. You can also look at the `.log` file to see what you're using. The first couple of lines tell you.

Comment: I am using (at least I think I am using) pdfTeX.  Although the tab next to the "Typeset" button reads "LaTeX".  So I am not certain whether I am using Tex or pdfTeX.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using TeX or pdfTeX, you can load one of several packages to set your default document font to a Garamond. If you are using LuaTeX or XeTeX, you can choose from any font installed for your system.

Here are some options for the traditional engines. The [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) can be used to find information about TeX fonts for these cases.

EB Garamond:

[image: EB Garamond]

This would be my preference.

`garamondx`:

[image: garamondx]

This is an extended version of EB Garamond which ignores the font's typographical context.

Cormorant Garamond:

[image: Cormorant Garamond]

This is a new package about which I know nothing.

In the code below, `ebgaramond` is enabled. The alternative lines for the other options above are commented. `ebgaramond` and `CormorantGaramond` are included in current TeX Live, but `garamondx` can't be. If you want to use this package, download the [`getnonfreefonts` script](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) and use it to install the package. Licensing means it cannot be included in the main distribution.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
% \usepackage{garamondx}
% \usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\begin{document}
  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps explain the step of loading "one of several packages to set your default document font to a Garamond."?

Comment: OK: so I tried using the \usepackage{garamondx} and got the message that "garamondx.sty" is not found.

Comment: @peewee In the preamble, `ebgaramond` is loaded. The lines to load `garamondx` and `CormorantGaramond` are commented. If you want one of those two, comment the line for EB Garamond and uncomment the line you want.

Comment: @peewee Try either of the other two. `garamondx` is available using the `getnonfreefonts` script if you're using TeX Live, but the other two are part of the default distribution.

Comment: god I feel so stupid right now.  I will get back to you in a bit---let me try to figure it out.  Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @peewee Thanks for the comments. I've edited my answer to try to clarify things a bit and provide some links etc. I should have remembered that `garamondx` is not in TeX Live.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [Garamond Libre](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/garamond-libre/), though it is recommended for LuaTex and Xelatex it works very well also with pdflatex and fontenc. If you write only in English you can drop the fontenc requierment-just `\usepackage{garamondlibre}`.

Comment: Nice, I hadn't noticed that there is support for pdftex too now. May I suggest you add a little remark in this sense? The Type1 fonts seem to be quite recent (maybe this very year) and most users here associate Garamond Libre with Unicode engines only.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me: (instructions for Debian/Ubuntu)

First, install LuaTeX:
`sudo apt install texlive-luatex`

Then, install EB Garamond:
`sudo apt install fonts-ebgaramond`

Finally, enable Garamond for your document by adding the following to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}                                                                                                                       
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
```

You should now be able to compile your document to PDF with Garamond by running `lualatex document.tex`.