# How can I use the installed "Adobe Garamond Pro" font?

Tags: fonts, pandoc

I am using `pandoc` to convert .txt to .pdf. I was trying to use the font `Adobe Garamond Pro` which I installed on my Mac, but I couldn't generate a .pdf file with the font (it keeps displaying the document with the default font.) I installed `MacTex`.

```
mainfont: Adobe Garamond Pro
fontsize: 12pt
documentclass: article
```

```
 pandoc test.txt -s -o test.pdf --pdf-engine=lualatex -C
```

---

Okay now it's working, except the fact that every letter is now bold. Not sure why-- I double checked that I installed also regular font for Adobe Garamond Pro, and I can use it in other apps such as Microsoft Word. Any idea to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. I guess your snippet is from your *yaml* front matter. Maybe try converting to Latex and look at the `.tex` file to find out which font commands are produced: `pandoc -s test.txt -o test.tex`.

Comment: Furthermore, Your `-V` argument seems useless since you're not defining a variable after it. `--pdf-engine` works without such an modificator. Try to remove the `-V`, maybe it prevents the `--pdf-engine` argument from working properly.

Comment: If you want to use fonts installed in your system, you need to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` engines. Try [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406816/how-can-i-get-a-garamond-font) if your engine is `pdflatex`. There's also a link to [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: Assuming you're using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document, have you tried loading the [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package and issuing the instruction `\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}`?

Comment: Oh I guess deleting -V argument seems working! But it uses for some reason bold font so every letter got bold...

Comment: OK, so you're on step further to solving the problem. Maybe now you try converting to `.tex` file and take a look or post the lines containing the font options which Mico just mentioned.

Comment: @lukeflo Thanks for the answer! I tried xelatex engine, and somehow it worked. I don't know why it didn't work for lualatex though..

Comment: So, now you got the output you wanted?

Comment: Yes I got the output. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Then please mark the question as solved by accepting the answer, so other people with a similar problem can find the solution which worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems to solve the problem, I post my suggestion as answer:

The argument `-V` in the pandoc command expects a following variable. Thus, it interprets the `--pdf-engine` argument as variable and prevents that the latter is processed properly. Deleting the `-V` argument lets `pandoc` handle the `--pdf-engine` argument correcty.

Why it works only with `xelatex` instead of `lualatex` is hard to find out without further informations. But as long as no special *lua* attributes are needed, `xelatex` is all good.