# Is normal Garamond a part of installed font for Latex?

Tags: fonts, pandoc, garamond

I was trying to use Garamond for my pdf document by using pandoc, but it seems that there is no fontfamily for a normal Garamond although it is in the catalogue(https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamond/). How can I use the font by using pandoc? If I use "fontfamily: urw-garamond", I got an error message saying that "! LaTeX Error: File `urw-garamond.sty' not found." if I use "mainfont: Garamond", it just generates the pdf document with the default font, not with Garamond. I installed the most recent version of Mactex.

```
fontfamily: urw-garamond
fontsize: 12pt
margin-left: 1.5in
margin-right: 1.5in
margin-top: 1.5in
margin-bottom: 1.5in
indent: true
documentclass: article
```

`pandoc test.txt -s -o test.pdf`

Comment: Please clarify how this posting differs from your [earlier query](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/694502/5001).

Comment: The font catalogue tells you under the `usage` section how to use this font, but with lualatex I would suggest to use a system font instead of the mathdesign package.

Comment: MikTeX lists a variety of garamond packages, such as `\usepackage{ebgaramond}`.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry, still not working. Maybe my MacText doesn't have the font so that I need to download it?

Comment: @kcho17 If you did a complete installation, it will be included in mactex

Comment: @ samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am receiving this message when I compile it. Thanks for help btw! ```</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/mathdesign/mdugm/md-gmr8
t.pfb>
!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ugmm8a.pfb): cannot open Type
 1 font file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!```

Comment: What @JohnKormylo wrote. But since you're using `pandoc`, try putting the line `fontfamily: ebgaramond` in your `yaml` front matter and compile using `pdflatex`.

Comment: @lukeflo Thanks for the answer. But I am trying to use normal "Garamond" that is listed on the website, not "EB Garadmond". I could use the latter, but not the former.

Comment: You could try out the [`getnonfreefonts`](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) script which adds two classical Garamond styles (I used the X version in my first master thesis, looks great). You might want take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i#255711), but for me it worked.

Comment: @lukeflo But it's not only Garamond that I can't use in the catalogue. Any font that is not listed as [OTF or TTF available], I can use the the font with pdflatex engine an d keep getting messages *.sty file is not found. So I thought that there must be some systematic error here.

Comment: Ah OK. That wasn't clear to me from your question.