Help with Installing Garamondx
Back at it again with another episode of I know nothing about LaTeX but still somehow am using it to write my papers because I think it makes my writing look pretty.  So today I am trying to figure out how to install Garamondx.  I am currently using Garamond EB, but I've seen a couple of other students around me using Garamondx, and it strikes me as a prettier font.  But every time I run it, I keep getting some sort of error message.  I meandered the exchange a bit and googled some stuff and it appears that I have to do some sort of manual installation of it, but I have no idea how to go about doing this and can't even figure out how to follow the available installation instructions. Can someone make it plain and simple for me? I have a macbook with Sonoma 14.4.1 installed, and am pressing "LaTeX" to create my documents.
Please let me know if you need any other info, and thanks to you all out there for existing. Here is my little code thing:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\geometry{margin=1.5in,top=1.5in}
\title{{\large{}}}

\date{}
\author{\normalsize{}}
\singlespacing

\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}
\usepackage[md]{titlesec}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


welcome! please paste your code as text and format it with the {}. never post images of either code or errors: they cannot be searched, cannot be copy-pasted to text solutions and are useless to people who depend on screen-reading software to navigate the site.

Ok! So I'll do that now, thanks for showing me some of the ropes!

your source appears to be using ebgaramond so it is not clear what you tried. I have no clue what Garamond dx refers to, so you should at least include a link to wherever you obtained the package or font. Edit: a web search turned up one irrelevant hit for garamond dx.

\usepackage{garamondx} This is the font I think I am trying to refer to. here is another source where the different garamond fonts are being discussed---I want to use the garamond dx font instead of the one I am currently using, garamond EB: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406816/how-can-i-get-a-garamond-font

Maybe you mean https://www.ctan.org/pkg/garamondx?

Yeah, I think that's the one!

how did you install tex?

I downloaded it from here about a year ago (haven't updated it since): https://www.tug.org/mactex/.

You can install garamondx and a selection of other non-free fonts using this script, if you are using TeX Live and have a local installation.

Download the installer install-getnonfreefonts to an arbitrary
directory Go (cd) into the directory containing the downloaded file
run:    texlua install-getnonfreefonts
Alternatively, if you prefer the command line, run
wget https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
texlua install-getnonfreefonts
Some systems (Mac OS X, BSD) provide curl instead of wget. In this case type
curl --remote-name https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/install-getnonfreefonts
texlua install-getnonfreefonts

This installs getnonfreefonts, which you can use to install various fonts, including garamondx. Make sure you use the sys option, which will require you to authenticate during installation, to avoid problems later.
sudo getnonfreefonts --sys --lsfonts

will show what is available.
sudo getnonfreefonts --sys --all

will install everything available.

Thanks for trying, but I have no idea what you are communicating to me.  I understand to copy and paste the text somewhere, like a word document or something.  But I don't know what to do past that.

@Yal I tidied a bit before the mods get us for littering. I think I had the wrong link earlier. use the one now in my answer instead. I think it will make more sense ;). sorry about the inconvenience.

Ok, let me give it a go.  (By the way, the name of the font I want to use is "garamondx", and not "garamond dx".)

Ok, so I press the new link, then what? (I also deleted some of my earlier notes.) Do what you said earlier: " download it, change to the directory containing it and try perl getfont.pl --help or just perl getfont.pl and it will likely tell you what to do. I couldn't find any separate instructions yet, which doesn't mean there aren't any!" ??

@Yal the link in my answer is to a page with instructions for downloading and installing.

@Yal see edit above. ignore my previous instructions. they were just wrong - sorry.

@Yal if you can use a unicode engine, as wipet suggests, that is easier but do NOT use wipet's code in a latex document.

Ok so I downloaded install-getnonfreefonts.  When I go to the folder in my downloads on my macbook and press the download, I am sent to a black screen with a lot of white script and letters.  What do I do at this point?

@Yal which application are you in? close the file, open Terminal and cd to wherever you downloaded it to. then texlua install-getnonfreefonts. this isn't a regular os x package. there's no graphical installer. you have to use the command line.

@Yal Terminal is an application on your macbook which you may not have used before ....

Is there anyway for us to chat more quickly? You are definitely trying to help, and I am definitely trying to follow your instructions.  Is it normal to connect with people through whats app on here or something like that? I know we're on the internet and total strangers, but I am really trying to get this font installed. If not no worries -- I'll keep asking questions through here.

@Yal you can 'chat' or create a dedicated chat room, but I don't think you have sufficient reputation. the rules are very annoying at times .... let me try to find out what you'd need ...

Oh goodness, this sucks.  I don't even know how to follow the instructions you're giving me...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Yal follow the link ^^.

I don't now where is the sources of non-free Garamond fonts you want to use. But I belive that these fonts are today in OpeType format, it means the suffix is .otf or .ttf. Simply copy these fonts to your computer and you have several options:

copy these files to the directory where your TeX document is or
copy these files to TeX distribution where another OpenType fonts are and run texhash or
install these fonts into your operating system

Then you can use these fonts directly by extended \font primitive in Unicode TeX engines (like luaTeX or XeTeX). Don't use obsolete pdfTeX which doesn't support Unicode fonts. We can ignore all complications with "font installing", i.e. converting then to non-Unicode old formats and generating old additional files like tfm, vf, enc, fd, etc., if we are using modern TeX engine which supports Unicode fonts directly.
Of course, if you are reading an old manuals about font installing then they will lead you into the thicket of complications related to the fact that old non-Unicode TeX engine is used. Simply recommendation: don't use old non-Unicode TeX engine (pdftex) and ignore these complications.
For example, I downloaded four files from this source and I saved it to the current directory where I have the testing TeX file. Then I created the testing tex file
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\gararm=GaramondNo8-Reg
\font\garait=GaramondNo8-Ita
\font\garabf=GaramondNo8-Med
\font\garabi=GaramondNo8-MedIta

\gararm The GaramonfNo8 Regular is here.
\garait The GaramonfNo8 Italic is here.
\garabf The GaramonfNo8 Medium is here.
\garabi The GaramonfNo8 Medium Italic is here.
  
\bye

and I run
luatex test

I have the fonts in the testing pdf output. No complications about "installing fonts", generating obscure old files like tf., map, enc, vf, fd etc.

Ok, so. I pressed on the "this source" link you provided in your post.  How do I download the four files? What four files are you referring to?

On tab '<> Code' you can get it with 'download ZIP'
